# selenium webdriver take too much time in .get() method and then unconditionally stop my whole java process.(It is only for one specific URL only)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

friends i am using selenium webdriver to fetch pagesource in my java desktop application. I am getting problem with only one URL which is "http://www.greenbergdental.com/offices/university" every time I try to get this my current java thread was stuck and whole application was stopped. Please suggest me some solution regarding this I have tried Pagetimeout, Scripttimeout. 
Note: I can not enable javascript for some reason. so please dont give me suggestions like turn on javascript that I can't.

```
 websiteURL ="http://www.greenbergdental.com/offices/university";
 WebDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
 htmlUnitDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 htmlUnitDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 htmlUnitDriver.get(websiteURL);
 String pagesource = htmlUnitDriver.getPageSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running for a specific browser (though web apps better be neutral of recent browser is used). If you are using latest `firefox` browser, try this:

```
HtmlUnitDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
```

For `chrome`:

```
HtmlUnitDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
```

Also, you could go for setting driver with `capabilities`:

```
HtmlUnitDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```